# How do I highlight a word in vim automatically?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim

I want to highlight a certain word regardless of filetype.  In my .vimrc I added:

```
highlight link notes todo
syntax match notes contained "TODO"
syntax match notes contained "NOTE"
syntax match notes contained "!!!"
syntax match notes contained "???"
```

Note: I also tried `syntax match notes "TODO"` (without the contained).

Unfortunately, I can't actually get any of these keywords to be highlighted.

**EDIT:**

I moved the code to `.vim/after/syntax/html.vim` in order to get the syntax applied. It currently looks like:

```
syntax match todo contained "\<\(TODO\|NOTE\|!!!\|???\)"
```

Now when I type `:syntax` I get `Todo           xxx match /\<\(TODO\|NOTE\|!!!\|???\)/  contained`

But, when I try to type an html comment with TODO in it (ie `<!-- TODO something -->`) no highlighting is applied.

Also, would I have to create a `.vim/after/syntax/file_type.vim` for each file type, or can I apply this generally somehow?

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround to global highlighting is to attach the keywords to an existing syntax group. In your .vimrc:

```
function! HighlightAnnotations()
  syn keyword vimTodo contained HACK OPTIMIZE REVIEW
  syn keyword rubyTodo contained HACK REVIEW
  syn keyword coffeeTodo contained HACK OPTIMIZE REVIEW
  syn keyword javaScriptCommentTodo contained HACK OPTIMIZE REVIEW
endfunction
autocmd Syntax * call HighlightAnnotations()
```

I'm appending to existing Todo types for languages I commonly use. I'm being lazy by adding it to all file types but you could be more specific if you wanted.

To find an existing group, open a file with the extension you're interested in and run `:syn list`. Vim will provide a list of all syntax groups currently loaded.

Hopefully this will be a passable solution until you can figure out a way to do this across all file types.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words) recipe contains a script plus instructions to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the table with this, but I got it to work by adding these three lines to my html.vim syntax file which I have in `$HOME/vimfiles/after/syntax:`

```
syntax keyword htmlTodo contained todo<br>
syntax match htmlComment /<!--.*/ contains=htmlTodo<br>
hi def link htmlTodo Todo
```

I'm only using "todo", but the list could be expanded by adding more keywords, i.e. syntax keyword htmlTodo contained todo hack test review...

An alternative:
Remove the syntax match ... line and add the following:

```
syntax clear htmlComment
syntax clear htmlCommentPart
syntax region htmlComment                start=+<!+      end=+>+  contains=htmlCommentPart,htmlCommentError,@Spell,htmlTodo 
syntax region htmlCommentPart  contained start=+--+      end=+--\s*+  contains=@htmlPreProc,@Spell,htmlTodo
syntax region htmlComment                  start=+<!DOCTYPE+ keepend end=+>+
```

Comment: I discovered that this only works if "todo" and <!-- are on the same line, so it wouldn't work for block-style comments.  Another solution is to replace the syntax match line with this code which will clear and rebuild the htmlComment and htmlCommentPart syntax elements.  I'll post that as another answer.

Comment: The `:syntax clear` was what I was looking for. Thanks.